Transition matrix associated to representative of element in $Out(F_n)$
There is a notion of transition matrix associated to elements in $Out(F_n)$ from Bestvina and Handel's paper that I am a little bit confused.
Let $\Phi\in Out(F_n)$ and $\phi:\Gamma\to\Gamma$ a homotopy equivalence being its representative, i.e. $\Gamma$ is a graph ($n$-rose) and $\phi_*=\Phi$. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be unoriented edges of $\Gamma$. Now, we can define the transition matrix $M$ as a $n\times n$ matrix whose entry $a_{ij}$ represents the number of times $\phi(e_j)$ crosses $e_i$. If this matrix is irreducible (and itself non-negative integered), by Perron-Frobinus we have a maximal eigenvalue $\lambda$ and one non-negative eigenvector which helps us to find a train track map of slope $\lambda$.
For example, consider $\Phi\in Out(F_n)$ such that $a\mapsto b,b\mapsto c, c\mapsto d, d\mapsto a^{-1}d^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}$. The transition matrix is
$$
M=\left[\begin{array}{l}0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1\end{array}\right]
$$ We now look for a metric encoded as $v = [\ell(a),\ell(b),\ell(c),\ell(d)]^T$ such that $Mv=\lambda v$.
Here is my first question: 1. The matrix multiplication gives us $\ell(d)=\lambda\ell(a)$ which is not quite right. We are looking for $\ell(b)=\lambda\ell(a)$ which is $M^Tv=\lambda v$. I am a little bit confused here.
My second question comes from the paper saying: "the $ij$-th entry of $M^k$ equals the number of paths in $\Gamma$ that originates at $j$ terminates at $i$ crosses exactly $k$ edges". However, we only label the edges but not the vertices. From the above notation, what I have is for example, $(1,1)$-entry of $M^2$ equals
$$
\sum_{i\in\{a,b,c,d\}}\#(\phi(i) \text{crosses } a)\cdot \#(\phi(a) \text{crosses } i).
$$ where I have trouble seeing the equivalence.
I am sure that if I carefully read the whole paper I'd find the answer. But I'd be appreciated if someone can elaborate it a little bit!

Regarding your first question, of course we are all taught in our first linear algebra course to multiply matrices by vectors with the vector written as a column vector on the right. But the thing to keep in mind is that you also have the option of multiply by a row vector written on the left. So a square matrix has both a row eigenvector, written on the left of the matrix, as well as a column eigenvector, written on the right. In this paper, for a train track map, the convention for the transition matrix $M$ is as you say: $a_{ij}$ is equal how many times $\phi(e_j)$ crosses $e_i$. That convention forces the "length eigenvector" to be the row eigenvector $[\ell(a),\ell(b),\ell(c),\ell(d)]$ written on the left, not the column eigenvector as you have written on the right using the transpose symbol. So if you multiply out $\ell M$ and set it equal to $\lambda\ell$ then you'll get, for example, $\ell(b)=\lambda\ell(a)$ as expected.
I'll add that the column eigenvector does have its place in the theory: it comes up later in the discussion of valence 2 homotopy.  It also has a geometric interpretation, as some kind of "width eigenvector".
Regarding your second question, you have perhaps confused yourself by adopting a notation $\phi : \Gamma \to \Gamma$ for the train track map that contrasts with the notation $f : G \to G$ used in the paper, and that then clashes with the notation for the "transition graph" $\Gamma$ that you are asking about. Following the paper's notation more carefully:

One starts with a train track $f : G \to G$.
One enumerates the edges of $G$ and uses that enumeration to construct the transition matrix $M$.
One then uses $M$ to construct a new oriented graph $\Gamma$ (a good name for $\Gamma$ is the transition graph of $M$). The vertices of $\Gamma$ are enumerated in one-to-one correspondence with the edges of $G$.
$\Gamma$ has $a_{ij}$ oriented edges from the $j^{\text{th}}$ vertex to the $i^{\text{th}}$ vertex.

And then follows the sentence that you have quoted.

Thanks so much for your answer and now it totally makes sense!!
